# When viewing a transparent texture through another transparent texture it causes a darkening of the one behind it

Tags: texturing, transparency

When viewing a transparent texture through another transparent texture it causes a darkening of the one behind it.

I am using cycles. In eevee the problem does not occur.

What would be the problem?

[image: Cycles View]

[image: Eevee View]

Comment: Maybe in the Render panel > Light Paths > Max Bounces, increase the Transparent value?